# Markdown like UI representation editor for app-config files (INI)

Tags: user-interface, markdown, app-config

I like the way markdown works.  It is just a simple text to represent in graphic format.  I'm curious if any similar one available for config file INI representations in UI format.  Is there anything of that sort?

**Example Config**

```
    [Game Config]
    Player Name = "John"
    //String
    Type=Football
    //Enumeration List
    //Football
    //Basketball
    //Volleyball
    Time in minutes = 45
    //Integer number
    //Game time in minutes
```

An UI representer would automatically represent in UI like below

[image]

Comment: I am afraid UI is more than just a content and layout. You need some actions or data binding as well. You would need to express them somehow.

Comment: In my sample code above, there is an imagined way of data binding via comments.  *Type* is an enumeration list with options like Football, Basketball and Volleyball.

Comment: What I meant was how will the application set the initial value for Type when displaying the Game Config and how will it obtain the resulting value? I think Scala GUI DSLs (including Scala Swing or ScalaFX) implement some of the spirit of what you suggest (they certainly provide automatic layout). I can imagine implementing what you want on top of them, but I doubt any such implementation exists, and I am not convinced implementing would handle the real meat of the GUI design.